# CRC - 16bit Lookup table using different polynomial notations

Tags: c, crc

I'm using a 16bit CRC and have a lookup table(LUT) generator, which produces a LUT for a given polynomial. The generator code I used uses the Koopman notation (e.g. 0x8810 for CCITT) and therefore produces the first table row as:

```
 0x0000, 0x8810, 0x9830, 0x1020, 0xB870, 0x3060, 0x2040, 0xA850,
```

I found a already computed CCITT-table with implementation on the internet however which apparently uses a different notation with the first line given as:

```
0x0000,0x1021,0x2042,0x3063,0x4084,0x50a5,0x60c6,0x70e7,
```

My question is: Do the short and long notations (0x8810 vs. 0x11021) produce the same results with different tables (i.e. the usage of the the LUT differs) or are the CRCs different using the same polynomial in different notations?

ps:*As far as I know 0x8810 and 0x11021 are the non-reflected Koopman/"normal" notations and 0x8408 and 0x10811 the reflected ones (for CCITT)*

pps: The "usage code" for the second table is given as:

```
uint16_t crc16_block(uint16_t crc, uint8_t *data, int len){
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        crc = (crc << 8) ^ crc16_tbl[(crc >> 8) ^ data[i]];

    return crc;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Koopman's notation represents a polynomial, but it is *not* a polynomial.  You cannot use it as an input to the lookup table generator you used.  Your first table is useless, since the implied polynomial does not have a low bit of 1.

Koopman's notation depends on the fact that all CRC polynomials end in a 1.  The polynomial always has a *+ 1* term.  When converted to binary, they always start with a 1 (the highest power of *x*), and always end with a 1.  E.g. 10001000000100001, or 0x11021, for the CCITT polynomial, *x<sup>16</sup>+x<sup>12</sup>+x<sup>5</sup>+1*.

The annoying thing about that number is that it takes 17 bits to represent.  You would like to have a notation that only uses 16 bits to make it easier to specify a polynomial in a computer program with 16-bit integers (or similarly, needing 32 bits instead of 33 bits to specify a 32-bit CRC).

There are two solutions.  Drop the high 1, or drop the low 1.  Usually you will see the high 1 dropped.  I.e. 0x1021, plus you then need to also provide the length of the CRC, 16 in this case.  So the specification is 16, 0x1021.  (There are other things you need to specify as well, but for now we will limit ourselves to the size of the CRC and the polynomial.)

Koopman realized that if you instead dropped the *low* 1, you wouldn't even need to specify the length, and still specify a 16-bit CRC polynomial in 16 bits.  You drop the low 1 by shifting down one.  So 0x11021 becomes 0x8810.  The high 1 is still there, so it implicitly defines the length of the CRC.

However, to make *use* of a CRC in the Koopman notation, you *must* shift it up by one and add one to get the polynomial for the calculation and the table.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed and comprehensible answer!